# should i use a 0-class on face verification via deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

im working on a face verification implementation, i have a lot of photos from a lot of people, in the 100 best cases, i have from 150 pics to 700, this 100 persons are the classes for the training. i also have a lot (like 100000) of pictures of 1 single person, my question is that if is worthless to create a "0 class" whit these pictures? i was wondering if the net would learn something useful from this class? when the net makes a prediction about a person that it never seen before, it would be more likely that it is going to be classified as 0 class? or do u have some topics for me to really understand whats going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are dealing with is that your dataset is unbalanced. This is a problem, because the Neural Network will predict class 0 with a much higher probability and still have a reasonable accuracy. You might want to consider resampling your dataset.

A way of resampling could be to undersample your dataset. You then only include the amount of samples from each class equal to the amount of samples the minimum class has. Say you have 
100 pics of person 1, 
160 pics of person 2, 
10000 pics of person 3 
You would then take only 100 samples from each of the classes in order to balance the dataset.